Infrared regularizing the harmonic oscillator path integral
This is from Laine and Vuorinen’s Basics of Thermal Field Theory. I do not understand why the fact that the integral over $x(\tau)$ implies the following regularization scheme. That is, I don’t understand why Eq. 1.52 (the fact that the average of $x(\tau)$ is $Ta_0$) implies Eq. 1.53 (that $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \mathrm{d}a_0 \to \int_{\Delta x/T} \mathrm{d}a_0$).



The product is the result of the integral for $n \neq 0$. The first term is $a_0$, the integral over the zero mode. That follows because $T a_0 = \Delta x$ via Eq. 1.52 and the following two sentences.

I understand the integrals for n != 0. What I do not understand is why 1.52 implies that we can rewrite \int da_0 as \int_{\Delta x/T} da_0.

What they mean is that you can think of $a_0$ like an abstract variable, say $x$, and you integrate $\int dx$ over an interval of length $\frac{\Delta x}{T}$. That range of integration is what follows from 1.52.

$a_0$ is the zero-mode of the Fourier-series of the position variable (1.45). It is therefore also the average (1.52) of the the position variable (up to a conventional normalization factor$^1$ $T$).  The IR regularization
$\int_{\frac{\Delta x}{T}}\!\mathrm{d}a_0$ means $\int_{-\frac{\Delta x}{2T}}^{\frac{\Delta x}{2T}}\!\mathrm{d}a_0.$
References:

M. Laine & A. Vuorinen, arXiv:1701.01554; p.7.


$^1$ Here $\beta=\frac{1}{k_BT}$ in units where $k_B=1$.
